# How facebook changes address bar

Tags: javascript, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML: Changing the URL without reloading the page?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5525636/html-changing-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Facebook can manipulate url bar by javascript without accessing to the page,

as example go to facebook home just open a photo you will see your url will get changed to something like

```
photo.php?fbid=4123..
```

they load the page by ajax but  can change address bar?

i'dont talk about url hash #photo/id_123414

Answer (score 2):

This is done with javascript's history.pushState()

Answer (score 0):

history.pushState:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries